# Terminator is not working on Ubuntu 14.04, says I need to "install the python bindings"

Tags: terminator

I have installed terminator using `sudo apt-get install terminator`, but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
$ terminator
You need to install the python bindings for gobject, gtk and pango to run Terminator.
```

I already have python(2.6.9) and python3(3.4.0) installed in my system.

Answer (score 3):

From the Terminator deb package:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.5), python-support (>= 0.90.0), python-vte, python-**gobject**, python-**gtk2** (>= 2.14.0), gconf2, libgtk2.0-bin, hicolor-icon-theme
```

So you shouldn't be able to install it without dependancies, unless you a) overrode the dependancies, or b) your system is broken. Try the following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gobject
>>> import gtk
>>> import pango
>>>
```

This will tell us *what* is missing, because one of those should fail for you. Then we can figure out *why* it is missing, and how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

After facing this issue for a while, I found out that it is caused by Anaconda3 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.

To fix it, I modified the first line (shebang) in `/usr/bin/terminator` file as following, to force it to run with the specific version of Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

It works fine with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` may give you an older version, which for 14.04 LTS may be incompatible, so to install the very latest Terminator:

```
sudo apt-get remove terminator

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Source: [official terminator page's install instructions](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html)

Comment: hi I tried this, but still getting the same output.
`You need to install the python bindings for gobject, gtk and pango to run Terminator.`

Answer (score 0):

it worked for be by updating python version to 3.10 in /usr/bin/terminator

#!/usr/bin/python3.10

Answer (score 0):

I've install python3.11 as an alternative python3.10 and set it as default python. After that my terminator stopped working. So, to use terminator i've change python back to 3.10

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

It helped. So, if you have the opportunity, roll-back python version.